# Bootstrap Collapsing Navbar goes wrong on Chrome for Android

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have a problem with the collapsing Navbar, it shows wrong on Chrome for Android, I tried stock navbar's without modifying and still happens ([www.tasqueo.com](http://www.tasqueo.com))
[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You have mixed content, your site is https and you are trying to load http files. Look your dev console you will see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Drip is correct,
So I came to understand one thing.
we have to use https for secured links especially for maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
or
If you give http:// in this code the output is coming like above.

MY CODE:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```